# Powershell : find value in a object and gets its corresponding value in another column

Tags: powershell

i have the following values in object $myData

```
Name    | ID
---------------------------
ABC     |  1 
DEF     |  2
```

i also have a string value `$val = "DEF"`

I need to find if the value in the string `$val` is available in `$myData` and gets its corresponding value in column ID

I tried the below code , but it not working properly

```
foreach($val in $myData.Name)
{
  if($myData.Name -eq $val)
  {
      $Curr_ID = $myData.ID  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to iterate/loop over all of `$myData` - not just the values in the `Name` property of each item, and then choose an iterator variable with a different name (otherwise you overwrite the value you already assigned to `$val`):

```
$val = 'DEF'

foreach($entry in $myData)
{
  if($entry.Name -eq $val)
  {
    $Curr_ID = $entry.ID
  }
}
```

A more PowerShell-idiomatic solution would be to filter the data using `Where-Object` in a pipeline statement:

```
$val = 'DEF'
$firstMatchingEntry = $myData |Where-Object Name -eq $val |Select-Object -First 1

if(-not $firstMatchingEntry){
  # No mathing entries found
} else {
  # At least one match found
  $firstMatchingEntry.ID
}
```